# Write 2 complex queries

Tags: query

I have a DB:

```
CREATE TABLE cabinet
(
    id_cabinet INT PRIMARY KEY,
    area INT NOT NULL
);
 
CREATE TABLE doctor
(
    id_pib INT PRIMARY KEY,
    speciality VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    surname VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    id_cabinet INT NOT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY (id_cabinet) REFERENCES cabinet(id_cabinet)
);
 
CREATE TABLE nurse
(
    id_pib INT PRIMARY KEY,
    pib VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    work_exp INT NOT NULL,
    fk_nurse_doc INT REFERENCES doctor(id_pib)
);
 
CREATE TABLE patient
(
    id_patient INT PRIMARY KEY,
    age INT NOT NULL DEFAULT 1,
    sex VARCHAR(6) NOT NULL,
    disease VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL
);
 
CREATE TABLE doctor_patient
(
    date_time TIMESTAMP NOT NULL, 
    id_doc INT REFERENCES doctor(id_pib),
    id_pat INT REFERENCES patient(id_patient),
    CONSTRAINT pk_doctor_patient PRIMARY KEY (id_doc, id_pat)
);
 
INSERT INTO cabinet(id_cabinet, area) VALUES (1, 12);
INSERT INTO cabinet(id_cabinet, area) VALUES (2, 10);
INSERT INTO cabinet(id_cabinet, area) VALUES (3, 8);
 
INSERT INTO doctor(id_pib, speciality, surname, id_cabinet) VALUES (1, 'surgery', 'Vacovskiy', 1);
INSERT INTO doctor(id_pib, speciality, surname, id_cabinet) VALUES (2, 'neurology', 'Obama', 1);
INSERT INTO doctor(id_pib, speciality, surname, id_cabinet) VALUES (3, 'dermatology', 'Atano', 2);
INSERT INTO doctor(id_pib, speciality, surname, id_cabinet) VALUES (4, 'pediatrics', 'Yeager', 1);
INSERT INTO doctor(id_pib, speciality, surname, id_cabinet) VALUES (5, 'surgery', 'Reeves', 2);
INSERT INTO doctor(id_pib, speciality, surname, id_cabinet) VALUES (6, 'psychiatry', 'Pines', 3);
 
INSERT INTO nurse(id_pib, pib, work_exp, fk_nurse_doc) VALUES (1, 'B.G.A.', 5, 1);
INSERT INTO nurse(id_pib, pib, work_exp, fk_nurse_doc) VALUES (2, 'J.L.B.', 7, 2);
INSERT INTO nurse(id_pib, pib, work_exp, fk_nurse_doc) VALUES (3, 'R.O.A.', 2, 3);
INSERT INTO nurse(id_pib, pib, work_exp, fk_nurse_doc) VALUES (4, 'S.T.J.', 10, 4);
INSERT INTO nurse(id_pib, pib, work_exp, fk_nurse_doc) VALUES (5, 'V.C.K.', 6, 5);
INSERT INTO nurse(id_pib, pib, work_exp, fk_nurse_doc) VALUES (6, 'M.H.F.', 4, 6);
 
INSERT INTO patient(id_patient, age, sex, disease) VALUES (1, 19, 'male', 'flu');
INSERT INTO patient(id_patient, age, sex, disease) VALUES (2, 24, 'female', 'diabetes');
INSERT INTO patient(id_patient, age, sex, disease) VALUES (3, 36, 'male', 'alergy');
INSERT INTO patient(id_patient, age, sex, disease) VALUES (4, 27, 'female', 'COVID-19');
INSERT INTO patient(id_patient, age, sex, disease) VALUES (5, 50, 'female', 'typhus');
INSERT INTO patient(id_patient, age, sex, disease) VALUES (6, 42, 'male', 'cerebrovascular disease');
INSERT INTO patient(id_patient, age, sex, disease) VALUES (7, 33, 'female', 'tuberculosis');
INSERT INTO patient(id_patient, age, sex, disease) VALUES (8, 21, 'male', 'chickenpox');
INSERT INTO patient(id_patient, age, sex, disease) VALUES (9, 23, 'male', 'flu');
INSERT INTO patient(id_patient, age, sex, disease) VALUES (10, 32, 'female', 'diabetes');
INSERT INTO patient(id_patient, age, sex, disease) VALUES (11, 40, 'male', 'alergy');
INSERT INTO patient(id_patient, age, sex, disease) VALUES (12, 62, 'female', 'COVID-19');
INSERT INTO patient(id_patient, age, sex, disease) VALUES (13, 54, 'female', 'typhus');
INSERT INTO patient(id_patient, age, sex, disease) VALUES (14, 37, 'male', 'cerebrovascular disease');
INSERT INTO patient(id_patient, age, sex, disease) VALUES (15, 20, 'female', 'tuberculosis');
INSERT INTO patient(id_patient, age, sex, disease) VALUES (16, 17, 'male', 'chickenpox');
 
 
INSERT INTO doctor_patient(date_time, id_doc, id_pat) 
VALUES ('2021-06-01 08:15:00', 1, 2), ('2021-06-01 09:10:00', 1, 3), 
('2021-06-03 10:00:00', 2, 1), ('2021-06-03 12:00:00', 3, 4),
('2021-06-04 07:45:00', 4, 6), ('2021-06-06 11:30:00', 5, 5),
('2021-06-07 07:15:00', 5, 7), ('2021-06-09 16:00:00', 6, 8),
('2021-06-07 08:15:00', 1, 9), ('2021-06-01 09:45:00', 6, 10), 
('2021-06-03 10:45:00', 2, 11), ('2021-06-01 12:00:00', 3, 12),
('2021-06-01 09:50:00', 4, 13), ('2021-06-06 13:30:00', 5, 14),
('2021-06-04 10:00:00', 5, 15), ('2021-06-09 15:00:00', 6, 16);
```

And for it I need to write the following queries:

- Find all patients who visited the doctor on the same day as patient "A"(example).
- Determine how many times each doctor has seen each patient.

Since I'm new to SQL, I spent a lot of time trying to make these requests, so I would be very grateful if someone would write these requests, so to speak, deadlines are burning. Thank you in advance <3

Comment: Welcome to the site! Can you share your work that you've done so far? Folks are much more receptive to helping get your partial progress done and working. All the information to complete the assignment is in your question, but answerers usually like to understand where you're having trouble, so they can focus explanation on that area, versus just doing a classroom exercise

Comment: concerning the patient table: don't store age, it is a function of the birth date, store that in stead.  Also, in your data, there is no patient "A".

Answer (score 0):

To find all patients who visited the doctor on the same day as a 'COVID-19' patient (example).

```
select dp.*, p.*,
       date_trunc('day',dp.date_time) vdate,
       dp2.id_pat pat2,
       dp2.date_time pat2_date,
       p2.*
  from doctor_patient dp,
       patient p,
       doctor_patient dp2,
       patient p2
  where dp.id_pat = p.id_patient
    and p.disease = 'COVID-19'
    and dp2.date_time >= date_trunc('day',dp.date_time)
    and dp2.date_time <  date_trunc('day',dp.date_time) + interval '1 day'
    and dp2.id_pat != dp.id_pat
    and p2.id_patient = dp2.id_pat
  order by dp.date_time, dp2.date_time;
```

see [dbfiddle.uk](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=703657455bc629c63968c2de64ad705b) for a postgresql 13 solution

Comment: Thinking about it, the days without a visit by a Covid-19 patient, must be few and far between.